# asp net web api 2 area routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, area

I have the following project structure:

```
Areas
-- MasterData
----- Controllers
-------- ArticleController.cs
-- ProjectManagement
----- Controllers
-------- ProjectController.cs
```

My MasterDataAreaRegistration.cs

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
      context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "API MasterData Default",
          routeTemplate: "api/MasterData/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

      context.MapRoute(
          "MasterData_default",
          "MasterData/{controller}/{id}",
          new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          namespaces: new[] { "iX.Service.Areas.MasterData.Controllers" }
      );
    }
```

My ProjectManagementAreaRegistration.cs

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
      context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "API ProjectManagement Default",
          routeTemplate: "api/ProjectManagement/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

      context.MapRoute(
          "ProjectManagement_default",
          "ProjectManagement/{controller}/{id}",
          new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          namespaces: new[] { "iX.Service.Areas.ProjectManagement.Controllers" }
      );
    }
```

I don't understand why both Controllers are available in both Areas.

```
api/ProjectManagement/Project
api/MasterData/Project
```

ProjectController should only be avaible in ProjectManagement.
Where do I have do change my code? And why?

My RoutConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          namespaces: new[] { "iX.Service.Controllers" }
      );
    }
```

And my WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
  // Web API configuration and services

  // Web API routes
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

  /*config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
  );*/
}
```

Thanks!